# Disable touch on Bamboo Touch&Pen CTH-460

Tags: multi-touch, touchscreen, wacom, graphics-tablet, bamboo

Running Ubuntu 11.04. 
Got a bamboo Touch&Pen CTH-460 and it works out of the box. The pen response works great but the finger response is horrible.
Is there a way to disable the finger response and only have the pen work?
The tablet clearly differentiates between the two, so there should be a way to disable one.
any thoughts?

Comment: I know it is a 8 years old post, but... doesn't the CTH-460 have a switch in the top right corner, to turn off the finger touch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found my solution.

Edit */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf* and add "Option "Touch" "off"" to each group. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the command line utility xinput. First use `xinput list` to find your device id:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Trackball                    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E3 Finger                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E3 Pen                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Webcam                                 id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

So in my case, the touch part has device id equal to `11`. Next, you set the `device enabled` property use `xinput set-prop`, like this:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ xinput set-prop 11 "Device Enabled" "0"
```

You can enable it again with:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ xinput set-prop 11 "Device Enabled" "1"
```

You'll have to do this every time you restart your computer. Also, the device id may change between boots.

Answer (score 1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9496609&postcount=1

There you'll find a script to disable/enable the touch AND a patch to fix the touch problem.
Worked perfectly with mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `xsetwacom`, which I think is a proxy for `xinput`, but for wacom/touch devices only. The id numbers in `xsetwacom --list devices` match up to `xinput list`.

Well, here's how to use `xsetwacom`:

```
this@this:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus                 id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen eraser                 id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
this@this:~$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen stylus           id: 10  type: STYLUS    
Wacom ISDv4 E6 Pen eraser           id: 15  type: ERASER    
Wacom ISDv4 E6 Finger touch         id: 11  type: TOUCH     
this@this:~$ xsetwacom set 11 Touch "off"
this@this:~$
```