# Disable touch of the tablet in Ubuntu Unity 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, wacom, bamboo

I've searched beforehand and the only suggestion I've found is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60069/disable-touch-on-bamboo-touchpen-cth-460#) but it doesn't work, at least not on my system (Ubuntu Unity 14.04 x64).

I need to disable the touch on my **WACOM Bamboo Manga CTH-470** tablet so only the pen tip and eraser are recognized and not my hand when I accidentally touch it.

I know of this temporary solution:

```
xsetwacom --list
```

to list the output of the tablet (example)

`inoki@innerdistance-Satellite-L650:~$ xsetwacom --list
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen stylus    id: 11  type: STYLUS

Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch  id: 12  type: TOUCH

Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen eraser    id: 16  type: ERASER

Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger pad    id: 17  type: PAD`

then

```
xsetwacom --set # touch off
```

Using

`inoki@innerdistance-Satellite-L650:~$ xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | cut -d ' ' -f 8
TOUCH
inoki@innerdistance-Satellite-L650:~$`

has shown only the "TOUCH" word exactly as above.

I need to make it permanent, so I don't have to insert the command every time I want to work with my tablet.

Comment: Add the command to your [autostart configuration](http://askubuntu.com/a/48327/187281).

Comment: That's a no go, since when the tablet is plugged out and plugged back in it changes numerical values for the touch option, for instance at first the identifier for touch can be 11, after re-plugging it it can be 13.

Comment: Could you maybe provide a sample of the output of `xsetwacom --list`?

Comment: @hal7df sure, see below:

`xsetwacom --list
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch id: 10type: TOUCH     
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger pad id: 11 type: PAD       
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen stylus id: 12 type: STYLUS    
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen eraser id: 16 type: ERASER`

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, but couldn't get it aligned. The numbers for the values vary each time the tablet is being plugged in.

Comment: FYI - when you provide something like output, you should edit your question so that you don't run into formatting issues.

Comment: Okay, so if you run `xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | cut -d ' ' -f 8` that should get you the id of the touch input. If you give that as an argument to your set command, it should always disable the touch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in my case worked this:

```
xsetwacom -v --set 'Wacom Intuos Pro M (WL) Finger touch' gesture off
```

test

```
xsetwacom -v --set 'Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch' gesture off
```

Comment: If you, like me, experience that while this command disables gesture but not tapping (i.e. finger 'clicks'), run the command again but then replace 'gesture' with 'touch'. So in my case: xsetwacom -v --set 'Wacom Intuos PT S Finger touch' touch off

Comment: I edited this older thread to show how to use the scripts on the tablet's buttons: http://askubuntu.com/a/118466/53256 . In this case, having a one-line command for toggling makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Rather than rely on fixed character positions and cut, you could use sed instead, like this:

```
xsetwacom --set `xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | sed -r "s/.*id: *([0-9]*).*/\1/"` touch off
```

Comment: Not really. The by me marked solution works like a charm and, most importantly, it is **memorable**. Your suggested method might work, but can easily be forgotten or mistyped. The working method can be applied by just creating a launcher and triggered each time the tablet is used. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: @Patrik This solution can be pasted into a script just as easily, and is generic, so it will work for other wacom tablets that have a 'TOUCH' device.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you still need to add the new command to your autostart configuration so that it's disabled to start with:

```
xsetwacom --set `xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | cut -c 40-42` touch off
```

Then try putting the following into a new file: `/etc/pm/power.d/99_touchdisable`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ac_power ()
{
    xsetwacom --set `xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | cut -c 40-42` touch off
}

battery_power ()
{
    xsetwacom --set `xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | cut -c 40-42` touch off
}
```

Then run `sudo chmod 755 /etc/pm/power.d/99_touchdisable`

Restart your tablet and try unplugging/plugging in your tablet.

If it doesn't work, check to see if you have different power profiles enabled. If it still isn't working, run `sudo apt-get install pm-utils` and try running `sudo pm-powersave <true/false>` to get it to run the script.

Comment: Followed your instructions, restarted the computer, re-plugged the tablet but still it enables the touch by default.

Comment: I doubt it'll do much but try removing the `exec` keyword (I'm not exactly the world's best scripter...)

Comment: Also, did it disable touch at startup, at least?

Comment: nope, nothing changed.

Comment: I changed my answer...try it now.

Comment: Didn't work, tried everything you suggested. As a side effect it removed transparency from the my-weather-indicator applet on the desktop.

Comment: Hmm...if you run the command in between the ```` signs, do you get the ID of the device back?

Comment: I only get the TOUCH word displayed, no numerical ID.

Comment: Okay. Could you please edit your question with the proper formatting of the example output I asked for earlier?

Comment: Edited, please check.

Comment: Try changing the '8’ after the `-f` flag to a 6.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: `inoki@innerdistance-Satellite-L650:~$ xsetwacom --set xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | cut -d ' ' -f 6 touch off
Cannot find device 'touch'.`

Comment: What about just the command to get the device ID? What does that output?

Comment: `inoki@innerdistance-Satellite-L650:~$ xsetwacom --list
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch id: 11 type: TOUCH     
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger pad id: 12 type: PAD       
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen stylus id: 16 type: STYLUS    
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen eraser id: 17 type: ERASER`

Comment: Sorry...the one including the `grep` and `cut` commands...

Comment: `inoki@innerdistance-Satellite-L650:~$ xsetwacom --set xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | cut -d ' ' -f 6 touch off
Cannot find device 'touch'.
inoki@innerdistance-Satellite-L650:~$`

Comment: Okay... change the 6 to a 7?

Comment: Still not working. Output is: `Unknown parameter name 'type:'.`

Comment: Okay, new command. See if this command gets the ID number by itself: `xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | cut -c 41,42`

Comment: The output is only "1", see: `inoki@innerdistance-Satellite-L650:~$ xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | cut -c 41,42
1`

Comment: Okay...change the `41,42` to `42,43`

Comment: The output is only "t".

Comment: `xsetwacom --list | grep TOUCH | cut -c 41-42`?

Comment: Nope, that was the 42,43, the 41,42 showed only "1".

Comment: No, sorry, I wanted to go back to `41` and `42`, changing the comma to a dash.

Comment: Still the output is only "1".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15590/discussion-between-hal7df-and-patrik).